# Heat transfer across a surface

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the difference between these 2 formulas ?

$$ Q = m C_p \Delta T \tag{1}$$

$$ Q = U \, A \, LMTD  \tag{2} $$

Both are heat transfer formulas . 2nd formula is the heat transfer across a surface. But isn’t equation 1 also heat transfer across a surface ?

When do I use each of this formula ?

Comment: I don't recognise that second formula. Assuming $U$ is the heat transfer coefficient, and $A$ the area,  I'd guess $LMTD$ is the thermal gradient though I don't recognise the notation used. Can you explain what the variables in your equations are?

Comment: @JohnRennie It seems to be the [logarithmic mean temperature difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean_temperature_difference). The formula the OP mentions shows up on that page.

Comment: Perhaps it is the MLT unit format?  Like Time in s is T, Length in cm is L?

Comment: @XcoderX It's definitely the Log Mean Temperature Difference.  That shows up quite a bit in heat transfer, and fits perfectly in the context. Though generally you would just write out the log mean temperature difference equation instead of adding an acronym to an equation; because that's confusing when there are also variables.

Comment: hmm... no wonder i didnt really understand.  perhaps OP could have clarified

Answer (score 1):

The first formula, expressed in terms of Q is fundamentally incorrect.  It is really a combination of the energy balance relationship for an open system $\Delta H=Q$ and the property relationship $\Delta H=mC_p\Delta T$, where m is the mass flow rate through the system.  The latter is the correct physical property relationship for the change in enthalpy with temperature for an ideal gas or for an incompressible fluid.  On the other hand, Q represents energy transport across the boundary of the system, and is path dependent.  So it should, strictly speaking, not be considered related directly to the physical properties of the flowing fluid (which are path independent).

The second equation represents the heat transfer rate across a boundary of a duct.  In the equation, U represents the overall heat transfer coefficient, including conductance of solid walls, and convective heat transfer to the flows on both sides of the solid walls.  LMTD is the log-mean temperature difference, and properly accounts for the temperature differences between the flowing streams (on either side of the wall) in cases where the difference in temperature is not constant along the duct.